# Update Column when date in other table is older then today

Tags: sql, sql-server

I habe two Table "Auftrag" and "Position".
"Auftrag" is the leading table, "Position" holds the "Auftrags".ID as Identifiyer (Positionen.FremdID)

I have the following problem:

In the table "Positionen" there is a columne named "Lieferdatum" (DateTime) and in the Table "Auftrag" is a columne "Status".
Now I will change the Auftrag.Status columne if the Positionen.Lieferdatum is older then today.

I have no Idea how I can handle this problem.

EDIT: There is a 1:X relationshipt between Auftrag and Positionen, so only when all "Lieferdatum" are older then today the Status should be changed.

I have tried this to get all the entrys:

```
SELECT Auftrag.Status, Positionen.Lieferdatum
FROM Auftrag JOIN Positionen
ON Auftrag.ID = Positionen.FremdID
WHERE Positionen.Lieferdatum < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Some Sample Data:

Table "Auftrag"

```
ID    Status
1     1234
2     89456
```

Table "Positionen"

```
ID    FremdID    Lieferdatum
1     1          2019-01-28 10:03:00.000
2     1          2019-01-31 11:00:00.000
3     2          2019-04-28 19:00:00.000
```

Output:

Only if, in this case both Lines in Positionen from Auftrag.ID = 1 are expired then then Status in Auftrag should be changed

Comment: When the `Lieferdatum` of just **one** corresponding row of `Positionen` is larger than today or when **all** corresponding rows have a larger `Lieferdatum`?

Comment: if all are larger

Comment: Does the `Select` get you what you want?

Comment: Not at all: there is a 1:x relationshipt between Auftrag and Positionen. with this Select I get all. But I will only Change the Status if all X are outdated

Comment: Can you add some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: I have added some sample data and the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no rows in `auftrag` without corresponding rows in `positionen`, which seems reasonable to me, you could use a `NOT EXISTS` to check for rows in `positionen`, that are after today. If for a row in `auftrag` now such row exists in `positionen` the rows in `positionen` must all have a `lieferdatum` before today.

```
UPDATE auftrag
       SET status = ?
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM positionen
                                WHERE positionen.fremdid = auftrag.id
                                      AND positionen.lieferdatum >= convert(date, getdate()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with your query other than using update instead of select.

```
UPDATE A 
SET Status = "yourstatus"
FROM Auftrag  A JOIN
     Positionen B
     ON A.ID = B.FremdID
WHERE B.Lieferdatum < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, please see my EDIT in the question